# Calculate Max Distance Between Polylines

Tags: r, r-sf

Is there a way to calculate the maximum distance between two polylines? I'm currently using the sf package to get the minimum distance, but I also need the maximum distance see the example below.

```
pts1<- data.frame(
  x= c(-103.485342, -103.482808),
  y = c(31.348758, 31.376947))
) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts1)<- "+init=epsg:2257"

pts2<- data.frame(
  x= c(-103.492822, -103.484231),
  y = c(31.348181, 31.377191))
) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts2)<- "+init=epsg:2257"

a <- pts1 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()
b<- pts2 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()

min_dist<-st_distance(a,b,by_element = T)

max_dist<- ???
```

Thanks

Comment: There's some extra ) where you are defining your data frames. The code doesn't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum distance (in a planar geometry) should always be between two vertexes, so cast to points, compute the distance matrix between the points of a and the points of b, and take the maximum:

```
> max(st_distance(st_cast(st_sfc(b),"POINT"),st_cast(st_sfc(a),"POINT")))
[1] 0.0304592
```

Note this is the distance along the dotted red line:

[image]

It might be that these two lines of yours represent something like the banks of a river and your real question is "how wide is the river at its widest", which would be between the two most southerly points in your example, but that's a different question to "what's the greatest distance between two lines".

Comment: Would you happen to know how to find the "widest distance" between the two lines "at its widest?"

Comment: Worth asking as a new question - it will require some additional caveats on your data such as defining the direction in order to decide what the "width" means, and how many points in each line and so on...